# PHP script with sleep() + AJAX returns one after another?

Tags: php, ajax, sleep

**Situation**:

Multiple AJAX calls are made to the same .php file at the same time, with different parameters

```
getInfo("keyword1");
getInfo("keyword2");
getInfo("keyword3");
```

The php does something very quickly, then sleeps for 2 seconds, then echoes its result.

```
//do stuff
sleep(2);
echo $myresult;
```

**Expected output:**

0 seconds: nothing

~2 seconds: all 3 results

**Actual output:**

0 seconds: nothing

~2 seconds: 1 result

~4 seconds: 2 results

~6 seconds: 3 results

Why is that? Why does the first AJAX call need to resolve before the next one starts on server-side?

Is this an issue with PHP where the same script can't be executed multiple times simultaneously?
How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure to include more detailed code so we can understand your situation more.

Comment: I don't believe specific code is necessary here, this is a general question about multithreading in php, any code with a sleep can be used for the question. It could be as simple as ```sleep(1); echo 'Hello world';```

Comment: Provide and your PHP code

Comment: What server are you using? (For example the built-in web server from php handles only one request at a time, also the default session handler in php is blocking.)

Comment: Hello @MiK use cache: false/true in ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

If you get sequential results, make sure that `session_start()` isn't used in your script together with sleep. Found the answer by chance but also thanks to Roland Starke for the comment.

Comment: [session_write_close()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) can be used to release the session lock.